# Application.html.haml file not rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am new to ROR .I am working on a project which was using erb files and I have now converted them in haml.

I have installed **haml gem** as mentioned in other posts but no luck!
and using rails 4.

The problem is this application.haml file is not rendered I don't know why .
Please help
**please let me know if any other info required**
**here is application.html.haml**

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title PipeCast
    %link{:rel => "stylesheet", :href => "assets/stylesheets/application.css"}
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = render 'layouts/shim'
  %body
    = render 'layouts/header'
    = yield
```

**here is application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  # protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  # before_filter :set_cache_buster
#
  # def set_cache_buster
    # response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    # response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    # response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  # end
#
end
```

**this is pages controller extending application controller but its not rendering application layout**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home 

     @greeting = "Hello Welcome to Ruby Web Application"
  end
end
```

**Server logs** You can notice here although all files are haml but it is rendering **pages/home.html.erb** dont know from where !

```
=> Rails 4.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-11-23 01:13:29] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-11-23 01:13:29] INFO  ruby 2.1.0 (2013-12-25) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
[2014-11-23 01:13:29] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=20082 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-23 01:35:39 +0530
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb (15.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 79ms (Views: 53.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-23 01:36:27 +0530
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-23 01:36:27 +0530
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-23 01:36:28 +0530
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: move first `= render 'layouts/shim'` under `%body` tag.

Comment: I did what you said but no luck !

Comment: do you have any other `layouts`?

Comment: no this is the only one ! I have also observed this thing was working all right when its in erb but when converted to haml rails dont pickup this appplication file!

Comment: `application.rb` it is name of `ApplicationController`?

Comment: Application_controller.rb is the name of application controller ! I changed the name in question above sorry !

Comment: can you post log line with render?

Comment: ... and i think you should use `gem "haml-rails"` instead `gem "haml"`

Comment: Tried both ways usin haml and haml-rails! Not working ! I will post dev logs in few minutes !

Comment: updated logs in question above you can check !

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need not layouts, but simple partials.

```
= render 'layouts/header'
```

When you use such construction, you are trying to render partial inside layout.

Make sure, that its name is 'app/views/layouts/_header.html.haml'

By conventions partials should begin from underscore character.

Comment: Header is a partial only with underscore prefixed with the name !

Comment: and do you have 'app/views/pages/index.html.haml' view?

Comment: i am using **root 'pages#home'** for my root in route.rb

Comment: yes, but you should have a view file for each your controller action.
If you render pages#home action, then you should have 'app/views/pages/home.html.haml' view
but your logs say that you render 'app/views/pages/home.html.erb'

Comment: I have aap/views/pages/home.html.haml not .erb ! thats my concern too ,from where it is getting this erb file ! I dont have any erb file in my app now !